# rosjava services AddTwoInts basic question

Tags: ros, services, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm looking at the client code (also the server) of AddTwoInts .. and I came across this code:

```
ServiceClient<rosjava_test_msgs.AddTwoIntsRequest, rosjava_test_msgs.AddTwoIntsResponse> serviceClient;
```

now my question is, who supplies the implementation of **AddTwoIntsRequest** and **AddTwoIntsResponse** ?
They are interfaces, with methods such as setA , setSum, etc.. but I can't find an implementation for these methods anywhere..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146161/rosjava-services-addtwoints-basic-question/) by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The implementation of the messages are created in runtime by some Proxy "magic". When you receive a message from a topic or a service, an implementation for those interfaces is created, allowing you to access and set it's members.

Damon Kohler explains this (very briefly, without diving too deep) in his talk where he presented Rojava: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATuVExlkirY

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0